# How to change org-mode settings to always include a certain preamble

Tags: org-mode

So currently I have this preamble for all my org files. Does anyone know how to make org-mode default to the above settings whenever I open a .org file?

```
#+STARTUP: latexpreview
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tcolorbox}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{amsmath}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\vsp}{\vspace{4mm}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\la}{\leftarrow}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\ua}{\uparrow}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\da}{\downarrow}
```

Comment: (setq org-startup-with-latex-preview t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can achieve this through `M-x org-customize`:

- Entry `Org startup / Org startup with latex preview`
- Entry `Org Export LaTeX / Org Latex Packages Alist`

  > Alist of packages to be inserted in every LaTeX header
- Entry `Org Export LaTeX / Org Latex Classes`

  > Alist of LaTeX classes and associated header and structure
  >   [...]
  >   The HEADER-STRING is the header that will be inserted into the
  >   LaTeX file.